# Chrome torn down the TLS connection after received server ChangeCipherSpec

Tags: tls, chrome

I met a strange issue that the TLS connection is always torn down by Chrome after received server ChangeCipherSpec. The sequence is as following:

```
  Client                     Server
  SYN-->              
                          <--SYN, ACK
  ACK-->
  ClientHello-->
                          <--ServerHello, Certificate
  ChangeCipherSpec-->
                          <--ChangeCipherSpec
  FIN-->
                          <--ACK
                          <--FIN
  ACK-->
```

Why **FIN** is sent instead of **Application Data**?

Answer (score 2):

Your sequence is weird. When the client sends the `ClientHello`, then the server will respond with a `ServerHello`, and then:

- either the client and server reuse an existing session, and do the "abbreviated handshake", in which case the server sends its `ChangeCipherSpec` and then a `Finished` message;
- or the client and server do *not* reuse an existing session, in which case the server must send its `Certificate` message and a `ServerHelloDone`, in which case the client will send a `ClientKeyExchange`, *then* a `ChangeCipherSpec` and a `Finished` message.

See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-work/20847#20847) for a description of the SSL handshakes.

In any case, if you observe a `Certificate` message from the server, then this is not an abbreviated handshake, and there should be at least a `ServerHelloDone` from the server, and a `ClientKeyExchange` from the client. The logical conclusion would be that your network capture tool *does not* see all the traffic. Therefore, it may miss the "application data" records that you expect.

Comment: I searched the material in the network, and it seems the sequence follows the TLS False Start used by Chrome except the FIN after the ChangeCipherSpec from server